# How to get the text from a csv file in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

I have an input tag:
`<input type="file" id="fileUpload" accept=".csv"/>`
that gets a csv file from the user. I then store the file into a variable as such: 
`const csvFile = document.getElementById('fileUpload');`
How can I get the contents of the file into one big string if possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the FileReader to read files.

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" accept=".csv" onchange="open(event)" />

<script>
  var open = function(event) {
    var input = event.target.files[0]

    var readerObj = new FileReader()

    readerObj.onload = function() {
      var fileText = readerObj.result
      //do something with fileText here....
    }
    readerObj.readAsText(input)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You should also include logic for the case where the file couldn't be successfully read, or where the use selected no file, etc. This is just a basic script for reading the file

Comment: Where did you get reader.result? It does not seem as if reader is defined anywhere?

Comment: @AJGoudel whoops, misnamed variable. Changed it now, should've been readerObj